# How to resolve a type that is being injected to a controller, with parameter override?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have a type named `Tracer` that is being injected to a controller say `LogController` and the constructor of `Tracer` takes a runtime parameter. Now that I have to use the `ParameterOverride()` option, but since the controller factory automatically resolves the constructor injection I cant do this by `ParameterOverride()`.So can anybody tell how can I achieve this?

Tracer:

```
 public class Tracer:ITracer
    {
        private readonly string _filename;
        public Tracer(string filename)
        {
            this._filename = filename;
        }
        public void TraceLog() //ITracer impl
        {
            Debug.Write(string.Format("filename is {0}",_filename));
        }
    }
```

LogController:

```
public class LogController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Log/
        private readonly ILogger _Logger ;
        private readonly Itracer _tracer ;

        public LogController(ILogger Logger,Itracer tracer)
        {
            this._Logger = Logger;
            this._tracer = tracer;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            _Logger.AddLog("index of log ctrl");
            _Logger.Save();
            _tracer.TraceLog();
            return View();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Unity Registrations

```
public static class DefaultUnityContainer
    {
        public static IUnityContainer container;

        static DefaultUnityContainer()
        {
            container = new UnityContainer();
        }

        public static  void Initialize()
        {
            container.RegisterType<ILogger, Logger>();
container.RegisterType<Itracer, Tracer>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(string)));
        }
    }
```

Controller Factory :

```
public class UnityControllerFactory:DefaultControllerFactory
    {
        protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
        {
            Type injectionType = null;
            if (controllerType == typeof(LogController))
            {
               injectionType = typeof(LogController);
            }
            else
            {
                injectionType = typeof (HomeController);
            }

            return DefaultUnityContainer.container.Resolve(injectionType) as Controller;
        }
    }
```

[image: error screen]

Comment: How/When do you determine the value of `filename`?

Comment: taken by config file

Comment: So basically its value is known at the time of composition. Why is the problem of using `ParameterOverride` then? Can you show the code where you attempt to use `ParameterOverride`?

Comment: @YacoubMassad i cant attempt to use `parameterOverride` because the unity automatically resolves the constructor injection of the `LogController` please see the controller factory section

Comment: This should work: `container.Resolve(injectionType, new ParameterOverride("filename", "myfilenamethatcomesfromconfigfile"));`. But please be careful, any parameter of name `filename` will have this value injected to it.

Comment: I am assuming that you can change the `UnityControllerFactory`. If you can't then simply create your own controller factory and tell the framework about it.

Comment: You can use `ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory` to tell the framework about your custom controller factory.

Comment: @YacoubMassad i did, but omitted for brevity.

Comment: You mean `ParameterOverride`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111618/discussion-between-necromancer-and-yacoub-massad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `ParameterOverride` like this:

```
return DefaultUnityContainer.container
    .Resolve(
        injectionType,
        new ParameterOverride("filename", "myfilenamethatcomesfromconfigfile"));
```

But please be careful, any parameter of name `filename` will have this value injected to it.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that we can also use the named registrations for this.In `DefaultUnityContainer`, we can register the constructor like this -

```
container.RegisterType<Itracer, Tracer>("GetFilenameFromConfigFile",new InjectionConstructor(ConfigHelper.Getfilename())); // provides the filename from the config file assuming its get initialized before the usage.
```

Then we can use dependency decorator in the constructor

```
public LogController(ILogger Logger,[Dependecy("GetFilenameFromConfigFile")]Itracer tracer)
        {
            this._Logger = Logger;
            this._tracer = tracer;
        }
```